# The left-hand of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason the code I have doesn't work it comes up with the debug error "the left-hand of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer", what does that mean? Any help at all would be awesome thanks!

```
void Update ()
{
    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("player");
    if (GameObject.FindWithTag ("player") = false) 
    {
        restart1();
    }
}
```

Comment: `GameObject.FindWithTag ("player") == false`

Comment: Or `if (!GameObject.FindWithTag("player")) { ...`

Answer (score 5):

You are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality-testing operator `==`.

The message is telling you can't assign to `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("player")`, the result of an expression.

You can avoid the risk of this error (which could run but cause unexpected bugs if the left-hand side were assignable) by just using `if (myCondition)` or `if(!myCondition)` rather than checking for equality to `true` or `false` when testing boolean values.

Comment: *You can't assign a variable in an if statement* This statement is wrong.  You can assign a value to a variable(even in if statement), but error is because you can't assign value to a value.

Comment: Since when C# prevents you from assigning in if statements? Before you comment, you could have tried it! -1 For misleading information, I'll remove my down vote once you remove it. thanks.

Comment: `bool x = false; if(x = true) { Console.WriteLine("assigned"); }` but it does warn you

Comment: @emodendroket [You are incorrect.](http://ideone.com/bK1s3T) You can assign in an `if` statement, but you can't assign to the result of a method call, and the `if` expression has to be (convertible to) a `bool` value.

Comment: @TimS. Ok, sorry, I was mistaken.  You can't do assignments of non-boolean variables but it looks like you can do assignment of bools.  I'm not sure why this is allowed since it is essentially never intended, and I suppose I never noticed the difference because writing `== true` or `== false` isn't really necessary.

Comment: @emodendroket You are still incorrect. Read the link in my comment: you can assign non-boolean variables. It is commonly used in the `while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)` pattern. Other than that, it is rarely used and if there's an assignment in an `if`, it's usually a mistake.

Comment: @TimS. That's true.  What I mean is you can't write `if (obj = obj)` because you'll get a type conversion error.